# Laravel подстановка маршрута

Tags: php, laravel

Как в **Laravel** использовать подстановку маршрута. Например:`$route['category/(:any)/page/(:num)'] = '/category/page/$1/$2';`

Comment: сидел бы на игнайтере и творил-бы свое, зачем потянулся в лару? :>

Comment: @Manitikyl Читал что вроде Codegniter в безопасности плох

Comment: меньше читай, с безопасностью у всех фреймов все нормально, отличаются только мировозрением, архитектурно и плюхами.

Comment: @Manitikyl Спасибо за совет

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Примерно как-то так:

```
Route::any('category/{id}/page/{page}', 'CategoryController@show')->where('page', '[0-9]+');
```

И сам контроллер:

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use App\User;
use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;

class CategoryController extends Controller
{
  public function show($id, $page)
  {
    return;
  }
}
```